# ssh-keys working when I ssh using the server hostname, but not when ssh using "localhost"

Tags: linux, ssh

So I have a server called "testone" which I setup my account "tmpuser" and "tmpuser2" to work with ssh-keys on.

I have it so I can successfully run the following after being logged into my "testone" host:

```
[tmpuser@testone]# ssh testone
Last Login: Thu Jan 20 11:37:00 2022
[tmpuser@testone]$
```

The above command works fine when specifying the hostname of the machine to ssh into (yes I am ssh into itself for this test).

I then attempt using the localhost alias and it fails:

```
[tmpuser@testone]# ssh localhost
tmpuser@localhost's password:
```

This fails and asks me for a password. I setup a secondary user called "tmpuser2" and can ssh into my hostname and localhost without a password.

Both users authorized keys are exactly the same. Any reasons why ssh localhost would fail with ssh-keys for certain users? Thanks.

Updated information based on Comments:
*Is there anything in ~/.ssh/config?* - Nope. ~/.ssh/ only contains authorized keys, id_rsa, id_rsa.pub, known_hosts.

*What do localhost and testone map to in /etc/hosts* -

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

testone resolves from dns to the ip of the server.
```

Comment: Is there anything in `~/.ssh/config`? What do `localhost` and `testone` map to in `/etc/hosts`, if anything? Please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: @roaima Updated question with results. No config and 127.0.0.1 for localhost. dns handles testone name.

Comment: Maybe a specific `Match` directive for tmpuser in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? Anything interesting when using `-v`, `-vv`, or `-vvv` for increasing verbosity? What do the syslogs tell?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you come out of your root shell and try it local account back to itself (or root back to itself). Make sure you're testing the same situation for `ssh testone` and `ssh localhost` in either case, please

Comment: @FelixJN There are no Match directives. There was however an error stating:
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory. The home folder had rwx-rwx-rx and I guess ssh is peculiar about ssh to localhost if these are off. Updated users home folder to rwx-rx-rx and it worked. If you want to post that as an answer, feel free.

Comment: @roaima Turned out to be incorrect home folder permissions for the user (had rwx-rwx-rx and localhost ssh keys failed). Changed to rwx-rx-rx and can now ssh to localhost without issues using keys. Thanks for your help!

Comment: All keys for that user (definitely as a destination, possibly also as a source) would have failed in that instance

Comment: @roaima Not sure what to respond with as I just looked over my history and the accounts and that was the only change I made.

Comment: @roaima is right: that `ssh` refuses connection due to bad permission settings is independent from the target being `localhost` or any other server. This is a pretty annoying problem because it only appears in the host syslogs/auth.log but `ssh -vvv` does not reveal this to the client.